# Getting data from an array, stuck on the first index

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Sorry for the title, didn't know what to write.

I have a google map and I am populating it with markers from a javascript array, the markers have numbers on them and that number is randomly generated with a `Math.floor()` function.

All works well so far, the markers show in their correct locations each with a random number on it.

The problem is when I click on the marker, I am displaying the country's name and the generated number on it. So for example if the marker over Rome saying "13" the window should say `"Rome. There are 13 stories in Rome"`

The problem is with the randomly generated number. It always gives me the value of the first country in the array, in this example it's `Beirut`.

So to recap, let's say Rome has 13 stories and Beirut has 45 stories, when I click on the marker of Rome, I get `There are 45 stories`

```
var locations = [
                ['Italy 3', 45.343294, 8.853324, 16],
                ['Italy 2', 44.534529, 10.303519, 15],
                ['Italy 1', 41.416810, 15.313285, 14],
                ['Bulgaria', 42.235462, 23.838675, 13],
                ['Albania', 41.317868, 20.147269, 12],
                ['Turkey 2', 39.714402, 32.803519, 11],
                ['Turkey 1', 37.968918, 29.200003, 10],
                ['Romania 2', 44.251917, 25.464652, 9],
                ['Romania 1', 45.651325, 22.476371, 8],
                ['Bosnia', 43.872979, 17.246879, 7],
                ['Serbia', 43.841292, 20.718558, 6],
                ['Athens', 37.977984, 23.741343, 4],
                ['Istanbul', 41.2440257, 29.0616179, 5],
                ['Rome', 41.851999, 12.555716, 3],
                ['Berlin', 52.481801, 13.291800, 2],
                ['Beirut', 33.787747, 35.796924, 1]
            ];

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var markernumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + markernumber + '|F6DD0E|000000'
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + '<br>There are ' + markernumber + ' stories.');
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include markernumber in the function closure for the marker click event.  Change:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + '<br>There are ' + markernumber + ' stories.');
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
})(marker, i));
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, markernumber) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + '<br>There are ' + markernumber + ' stories.');
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
})(marker, i, markernumber));
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xvcho49o/)

Reference question: [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) (only has closure on marker and i, because that is all it uses)

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var locations = [
    ['Italy 3', 45.343294, 8.853324, 16],
    ['Italy 2', 44.534529, 10.303519, 15],
    ['Italy 1', 41.416810, 15.313285, 14],
    ['Bulgaria', 42.235462, 23.838675, 13],
    ['Albania', 41.317868, 20.147269, 12],
    ['Turkey 2', 39.714402, 32.803519, 11],
    ['Turkey 1', 37.968918, 29.200003, 10],
    ['Romania 2', 44.251917, 25.464652, 9],
    ['Romania 1', 45.651325, 22.476371, 8],
    ['Bosnia', 43.872979, 17.246879, 7],
    ['Serbia', 43.841292, 20.718558, 6],
    ['Athens', 37.977984, 23.741343, 4],
    ['Istanbul', 41.2440257, 29.0616179, 5],
    ['Rome', 41.851999, 12.555716, 3],
    ['Berlin', 52.481801, 13.291800, 2],
    ['Beirut', 33.787747, 35.796924, 1]
  ];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var markernumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + markernumber + '|F6DD0E|000000'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, markernumber) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + '<br>There are ' + markernumber + ' stories.');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i, markernumber));
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```